# How to trigger a webhook after azure pipeline run completes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-runbook

I have an azure runbook that has some Python code. And this runbook needs to be triggered as soon as an azure pipeline runs successfully. Note: I cannot make changes to the pipeline steps or the pipeline. This should be done via configurations or some workarounds.

Our customers have 100s of pipelines/pipeline jobs, so changing the pipelines to 'add' one more step to trigger the webhook is not feasible.

Comment: How about creating a job that listens on the pipline results and hook from there. I'm not aware on a post-run hook from within Azure DevOps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved through the webhooks functionality natively offered by Azure DevOps, see: [Webhooks with Azure DevOps - Azure DevOps | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks).

If the pipelines are YAML pipelines or classic build pipelines then you'll want to select the **Build completed** event type.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

simon-pearson's method is correct.

We can use the [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) in **Azure DevOps Project Settings -> Service Hooks -> Webhook** to run the Post method to trigger the Azure Runbook.

I would like to share more detailed steps about complete the process:

Step1: Create the Webhook in Azure Runbook. We can record the Webhook URL.

[image]

Step2: Navigate to **Azure DevOps Project Settings -> Service Hooks -> Webhook**. Then we can select the Trigger event: Build completed  and patse the webhook URL to the URL Field.

[image]

**Result:**

When the Pipeline runs complete, it will trigger the service hook and trigger the Azure RunBook via the webhook.

Azure DevOps:

[image]

Azure Runbook job:

[image]